# How to display x axes value for each matplotlib subplot with secondary y axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I want to show x axis value on each subplot that uses a secondary_y axis. The output generated by this code shows x values only in the bottom two subplots. This code replicates a major project that uses a 7x3 subplot matrix

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df1=df1*100
ncols=2
nrows=2
i=0

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols,sharex=False) #
fig.tight_layout(pad=3)

col = ['A','B','C','D']
for r in range(nrows):
    for c in range(ncols):

        df1[col[i]].plot(kind='line',use_index=True,linestyle="-",lw=2,color='red',grid=True,rot=0,legend=False,ax=axes[r,c],sharex=False)
        ax2=axes[r,c].twinx()
        df2[col[i]].plot(secondary_y=True,kind='line',use_index=True,linestyle="-",lw=2,color='blue',grid=False,rot=0,legend=False,ax=ax2,sharex=False)
        i=i+1

plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: 2x2 subplot matrix]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your for loop and outside of the loop (after `i=i+1`), you can add back the x label to the first row with `.tick_params(labelbottom=True)` on each column of the first row.

```
axes[0,0].tick_params(labelbottom=True)
axes[0,1].tick_params(labelbottom=True)
```

For the entire first row, you could also more dynamically do:

```
for a in axes[0,:]:
    a.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
```

[image]